# extend build-pipeline of angular-cli

Tags: typescript, ember-cli, broccolijs, angular-cli, build-pipeline

Can i extend the build-process of angular-cli without rewriting angular-cli itself? Like in the old days, when i wrote my gulp/grunt tasks for the build-process and i could change everything i wanted.

I want to change the default build-system of the angular-cli. Inline the styles and html templates in production build, change the order in which the files are compiled, concatenated,.... Prevent compiling of sass files having "_"-prefix, like _home, _about. Pass some arguments/config to the build command.

Answer (score 2):

The build process is extendable in the same way the ember-cli is, you can refer to their [documentation](http://ember-cli.com/extending/).

By this method you will be able to override the existing build command and task and replace it with what you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, but with this i'am able to overwrite the whole build pipeline. But if i want to overwrite just specific build step, like the sass processing. As i saw angular-cli uses own sass-plugin which is hard-coded in the Angular2App. If i want replace this sass-plugin with my own implementation, because for example i want to overwrite the sass import function or add custom functions to sass.