# Extending Angular CLI tasks

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-cli

I'm trying to extend the default Angular CLI tasks, but I'm running into some roadblocks. At this point, I'm trying to extend it to add two additional tasks:

- Add in additional linting to support stylelint for CSS linting
- Add support for [doiuse](https://github.com/anandthakker/doiuse) to ensure all styles written support the browsers we need to support

I have tried a few things so far, however none of them seem to work. I've also taken a look at the [material-2 angular-cli-build.js](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/angular-cli-build.js) file, and have been able to get doiuse to work in a modified version of it, however it's still problematic and not properly catching errors when it finds invalid CSS.

Has anybody had any luck or have any tips they can suggest for extending the Angular CLI tasks?

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37302518/2906569), you can extend the build script as [ember-cli](https://ember-cli.com/extending/).

You can also look at the [ember-cli user guide](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/) for built in configurations that you can use without making any extension first